# How to search in all files using Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, file-search

I need to find all files on my Mac using some search criteria.

1. I open Finder
2. I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. Using "+" button I add any search criteria, even stack of them

but the search does not start – because in the very beginning I had to limit my search by typing any part of file name in the search field. But I need to find **all files** which satisfy my search criteria, without limitation on part of file name. What to do? How can I start the search with selected search criteria for **all** existing files? On Windows I would use a wildcard `*.*` to search for **all** files. How to search for all files in Finder?

All suggestions usually look like: "Begin to type what you need in the search field...". But this implies that you already know what file name you are looking for. In my case I need to include **all** existing files in my search using specified search criteria.

Comment: Have you tried using just plain `*`?

Comment: When using asterisk the results are strange and definitely not all files are included in the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to type any name at all, just start filling in your additional criteria boxes...

The search runs 'live', i.e. no Enter key needed to start it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! My search does not start "live", it shows any activity only after I type something in the search field. Probably I have some problems with my Spotlight, I will re-check it.

Comment: Welcome. Test it on something 'easy' like my apps launched in the last day search above.